# When setting jre environment parameters, should the java control panel system tab or the user tab be used

Tags: java, memory, controlpanel

If I am the sole user of my computer, does it make a different if I set java runtime parameters under the system tab or the user tab in the java control panel? When do you use one tab as oppose to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

*The User tab shows all of the registered JREs and JREs that the user has added. The System tab shows the JRE that was used to start the Java Control Panel.*

You can see more here:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/jcp.html